How to create a maven dependency and use it in Spring boot
I want to create a maven dependency Spring boot and use it in other project. But I have compile error...
[INFO] [1m--- [0;32mcompiler:3.13.0:compile[m [1m(default-compile)[m @ [36msso[0;1m ---[m
[INFO] Recompiling the module because of [1mchanged source code[m.
[INFO] Compiling 3 source files with javac [debug parameters release 21] to target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /D:/workspaces/test/sso/src/main/java/ir/com/sso/domain/entity/User.java:[3,35] package ir.com.common.domain.entity does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/workspaces/test/sso/src/main/java/ir/com/sso/domain/entity/User.java:[20,27] cannot find symbol
  symbol: class BaseEntity
[INFO] 2 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[INFO] [1;31mBUILD FAILURE[m
[INFO] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[INFO] Total time:  5.267 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-12-06T10:06:06+03:30
[INFO] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal [32morg.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.13.0:compile[m [1m(default-compile)[m on project [36msso[m: [1;31mCompilation failure[m: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /D:/workspaces/test/sso/src/main/java/ir/com/sso/domain/entity/User.java:[3,35] package ir.com.common.domain.entity does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/workspaces/test/sso/src/main/java/ir/com/sso/domain/entity/User.java:[20,27] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol: class BaseEntity
[ERROR] -> [1m[Help 1][m
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the [1m-e[m switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the [1m-X[m switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [1m[Help 1][m http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

my pom.xml in common project is:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    
    <groupId>ir.com</groupId>
    <artifactId>common</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>common</name>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <description>common project for extend</description>
    
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>...<dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

and my pom.xml in sso project is:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>        
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>ir.com</groupId>
    <artifactId>sso</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>sso</name>
    <description>Demo project for SSO</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ir.com</groupId>
            <artifactId>common</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    ...
    

My common project is build success. But sso project has error.

Remote the <type>pom</type> from your dependency...

Hello, I tested it. (pom and jar in common and sso). Thanks any way. I think spring boot can't be pom

No a spring boot project like that must be either packaging jar or war... becasue you are packagin content to a jar file ... which is the resulting application...

You can see your answer here:
Your question isn't here but your answer is here

I added this plugin in my parent pom.xml:
<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <classifier>exec</classifier>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>

after build, all of things is correct
